# violation of primary key - deduping table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table with 10 million records with a nonclustered index key on one column and I am trying to dedupe the table. I tried the inserts with select where either using a left join or where not exists; but each time I get the error with violation of key. Here are the queries I used;

```
insert into temp(profile,feed,photo,dateadded) 
select distinct  profile,feed,photo,dateadded from original as s 
where not exists(select 1 from temp as t where t.profile=s.profile)
```

This just produces the violation of key error. I tried using the following:

```
insert into temp(profile,feed,photo,dateadded) 
select distinct    profile,feed,photo,dateadded from original as s  
left outer join temp t on t.profile=s.profile 
where t.profile is null
```

I ended using a batch insert since the log file was growing too big but still get the violation of primary key error even on only 1000 records.

```
Destination Table :IX_Temp - profileUrl(ASC)--> unique key (non clustered)
Source Table: IX_PURL - profileUrl(ASC) ---> index (non clustered, not unique
```

Comment: Migrate to http://dba.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine that `distinct` isn't working as you expect here as the time portion will be slightly different.

A different approach would be to use `group by` and take the earliest `dateadded` to remove any duplicates.

Maybe something like this:

```
Select Profile,
       Feed,
       Photo,
       Min(DateAdded) as [DateAdded]

From Original
Group By Profile, Feed, Photo
```

Comment: I think this may just be working cause it's running now and has not stopped with error msg yet. Will post back when complete. thanks